# Select first autocomplete suggestion using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i would like to select the first autocomplete suggestion using the following code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

if __name__ == '__main__':
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service()
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         

  link = "https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/"
  driver.get (link)     
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@aria-label="Name"]'))).send_keys("Cummings")
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@aria-label="City, State or Zip"]'))).send_keys("Lynnwood")
  # input("Press!")

  waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//div[@class="autocomplete-suggestion"])[1]'))).click()   
  
  driver.quit()
```

I get the following TimeoutException error:

```
$ python temp1.py
Working for https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\mikayla_pivec\temp1.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver.quit()
  File "G:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

(when you check the website at the step where "Lynnwood" is entered to the input-field, you will see that the autocompletion is suggesting "Lynnwood, WA" and i try to select this value)

How can i select the autocompletion (so a search is afterward possible) on this site?

Comment: Unfortunately, this site can't be reached - it blocking requests by Cloudflare from browser / browser with VPN / even from Browserstack

Comment: I don´t understand - when i use my european homecountry ip-address i get blocked to reach the site. But when i use a vpn with an us ip address i have no problems.
And with that you should be able to get access and see what i mean.